# Can't scroll down on first page on mobile phone, there is no scroll bar (After refreshing page it works)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

i implemented a site (through small JS code) in my original website.
Everything works fine but yesterday i found out that when **i first load the page, there is no scroll bar**. **If i refresh the page, its possible**. I played a bit with the parameter 'height' but it didnt work.

Body-Code: `<heyflow flow-id="erp-berater-anzeige" height="2000" width="100%" pass-parameters scroll-up-on-navigation></heyflow>`

The page: https://entiac.com/erp-stellenanzeige/

*PS: Im not deep into coding*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to, first of all, add a css file or `<style>` tag in your index file, which will contain

```
body{
overflow: visible; !important
}
```

so you will be sure that isn't an issue. The site has some sort of scrollbar issue even on PC browser, so it would be better to set `height:100%`- hardcoded values like body height 2000px aren't a good solution.

Other good thing which you could do is divide your site in `<section> your code </section>`, give them `height: 100vh;` and make sure your js file loads in one of these sections. This way every section will be full height of your display **(100vh = 100 view height)**. Such a split will make your site bit easier to manage.
Cheers!

Comment: overflow and body: 100% didnt work :( Thanks anyway!